# Altering output format of split() in R

Tags: r, split

Suppose I have the following split:

```
x <- 1:5
K <- 2
y <- 5

split(sample(x), sample(1:K, y, replace = TRUE))
$`1`
[1] 3

$`2`
[1] 5 1 2 4
```

Is there a way to put the above into the form

```
      [, 1] [, 2]
 [1, ]    3     5
 [2, ]          1
 [3, ]          2
 [4, ]          4
```

Comment: If those empty spots in the matrix were NAs, then yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could fill those empty elements with NA using `length<-` then it would be perfect for the result from `sapply`.

```
a <- split(sample(x), sample(1:K, y, replace = TRUE))
a
# $`1`
# [1] 2 3
#
# $`2`
# [1] 5 1 4

sapply(a, "length<-", max(lengths(a)))
#       1 2
# [1,]  2 5
# [2,]  3 1
# [3,] NA 4
```

Comment: The issue is, I want to then randomly sample from the result of sapply(). Will this ignore the NAs?

Comment: @JarrettPhillips - `sample(na.omit(.))` will ignore the NAs, yes.  But then what's the point of putting the result into a matrix if we're not going to use it as such?

Comment: My goal is to populate an array with two levels, drawing randomly for the result of sapply(). For example, if x is an array, then x[,, 1] would contain values from column 1 of the sapply() result, whereas, x[,,2] would contain values from column 2 of the sapply() result. Values from sapply() would be assigned to the array according to some probability weights.

Comment: It seems that @RichScriven has answered your original question - if you have another one... then I think you should open accept this answer and open a knew one.

Answer (score 0):

One can try `tidyverse` based approach as it will provide flexibility to directly use `dplyr` chain. The logic is to `stack` list in data.frame and then use `tidyr::spread` to change data in wide format:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

split(sample(x), sample(1:K, y, replace = TRUE))  %>% 
  stack() %>%
  group_by(ind) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(ind, values, fill =  NA_integer_) %>%
  select(-rn) %>% as.data.frame()

#    1 2
# 1  1 2
# 2 NA 5
# 3 NA 4
# 4 NA 3
```